# Make spring rolls in advance

Tags: freezing, food-preservation, asian-cuisine

I'm making some spring rolls for a party on Friday. As I will not be able to make them the same day I was wondering what the best option would be. I will have the possibility of frying them directly at the place, but making them there would not probably be feasable.

What would you advice me to do?

1. make the rolls the night before, then freeze them and fry them the next day
2. make the rolls the night before, keep them in the fridge and fry them the next day
3. make and fry the rolls the night before. Reheat them (in the oven?) the next day (this sounds quite bad to me)

I think I will have some with pork, some with shrimp and some with veggies only.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best choice is number 2, get them all wrapped up and ready to go, cover them tightly and pop them in the fridge.

3 is possible but you risk them going soggy. They'll be fresher if you fry them on the day.

Comment: I've done the rolls, kept them in the fridge with some kitchen wrap on top and they were perfect!

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

I've done number two before, but typically the morning of, not actually overnight.

Even that short in advance, the wrapper will start to get sticky and gummy, so you have to be careful about how you store them.

I think the last time I did it, I rolled them in cornstarch before storing long term, but I can't recall if I still had any problems.  (I only tend to do it about once per year, not often enough to perfect the technique ... I think I also put something above them in the container (waxed paper?) so that there was less air to condense in the container)

Comment: I think I may actually try to do a few tomorrow and leave them overnight in the fridge to test the thing!

Comment: @nico : good plan ... if you're in a dry area, you might not see as much condensation, but it might be worth putting a paper towel down underneath, or similar.

Comment: @nico - did you test this, if so, what were your findings?

Comment: @DaveRook: yes, solution #2 worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

If you make them the night before and freeze them, make sure that they are separated by a liner so they will not stick together. Freezing them will dry the wrapper and will assist in making the wrapper crispier a little longer than if you were to do item 2.

I am not sure how long your commute will be, but do not let your lumpia thaw.  It will take the wrapper soggy.

When you are ready to fry, make sure nobody is allergic to peanuts if you are using peanut oil. Otherwise start with a high temperature, your lumpier will bring the temp down--so do not overcrowd them.  Lastly, beware of those who sample while you cook. You will end up with zero on your platter when you are done. Good luck.